# Get detailed response from ElasticSearch bulk indexing

Tags: elasticsearch

Indexing through ES bulk python gives only brief information in the response. I would like to get the detailed response that includes the complete document which got indexed. How can I achieve it?

The current response ES bulk provides is below:
{'took': 6, 'errors': False, 'items': [{'index': {'_index': 'abc', '_type': 'image', '_id': 'UUID', '_version': 2, 'result': 'updated', '_shards': {'total': 2, 'successful': 2, 'failed': 0}, '_seq_no': 245383, '_primary_term': 1, 'status': 200}}]}

Comment: add you request query in question

Comment: I am using SDK. All I provide it is the body for it.

Comment: Found that ES bulk method accepts 'params' which take optional attribute called "fields" with comma separated keys that you are looking for, in the response. Trying it out